# Installing Dependancies (noob level)

Tags: node.js, dependencies, installation, command-line-interface

How do I check and see if I already have installed certain dependencies? Also, if I install them twice what would happen? I'm just learning and apologize for silly question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Anyway, which dependencies are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the dependencies locally. Meaning, you install them for specific project then you can check `node_modules` folder in that particular project.

Apart from that, `npm` is smart enough to not install the sames dependencies again unless you specify newer version; In that case, it will replace the current one with the newer version.

Also, be careful if you install newer version of any libraries (in this context, node.js). Do read the change log (which is basically a document specifying new changes on the API) to safe you some headache.

It is because, for example, newer version might have new APIs and this might result in breaking all your code.